# Literature on Noninformative Priors for GPD

Tags: bayesian, references, prior, pareto-distribution, uninformative-prior

I am starting to do some work using the [Generalized Pareto Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution) (GPD), and was hoping someone might be able to point me in the direction of literature (or just general recommendations) on choice of "noninformative" prior for the parameters of the GPD.

Comment: [Stan](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations) has a wiki for priors. For GPD specifically, their [`gpdfit` function](https://mc-stan.org/loo/reference/gpdfit.html) uses `The weakly informative prior is a Gaussian prior centered at 0.5.`